# Simplest AVR programmer

Tags: avr, programmer

I  recently fried my AVRISP MKII programmer, so I am looking for a new programmer. What is the best AVR programmer according to the following criteria:

- Out of the box use
- Works well with Ubuntu
- Easy to use
- Able to program common types of AVR uCs (such as ATmega328-PU or ATtiny85)

Any recommendations?

Comment: I'm going to add my favorite cheap, easy to use programmer here, but I can't attest to its use with Ubuntu: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9825 Although, others have had luck with Linux using this tutorial: http://www.ladyada.net/make/usbtinyisp/avrdude.html#linux It also doesn't support things like debugging - just plug and play programming.

Comment: You can use an Arduino Uno as a programmer (ArduinoISP) if you have any of those around.

Comment: Yes, I have an Arduino, but I would like to use a programmer besides the arduino

Comment: @coding_corgi - Arduino ISP seems to satisfy all your listed requirements, so it would help if you could specify why you want something different.  Speed?

Comment: Using Arduino ISP would work fine... if you built a stand alone circuit. Using an Arduino board as a permanent programmer is silly given the cost of the board, the lost opportunity of the board, and the fact that you would be using a bunch of unmarked wires to connect the board to the target MCU.

Comment: I'm reluctant to say "best" but the usbTinyisp http://www.ladyada.net/make/usbtinyisp/ is fine. Works via avrdude on Debian so should be OK on Ubuntu too. Kurt's clone of it is probably OK too.

Comment: IIRC the usbtinyisp is *extremely* squeezed for program memory, in that its firmware will only even build with specific toolchain versions.  The idea is cool, but the use of that particular chip for the task is probably not optimal given today's choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, my experience with AVR programmers is really quite uniform regardless of which programmer I'm using. I have used several different programmers, from the SparkFun Pocket AVR to a cheap eBay AVR programmer that cost under $5. I didn't really notice better performance coming from a more expensive programmer as compared to the cheap eBay one. I'd just try a few and see which one you work best with.

Answer (score 1):

I use UsbAsp - works on all OS, is cheap.